# Custom dialog for enabling push notifications (iOS)

Tags: ios, push-notification

Is it possible to present a custom dialog and not present the default dialog "(AppName) Would Like to Send You Notifications" (seen below)?  So when the user presses the custom dialog button "Enable Notifications" it allows notifications w/o presenting the default dialog?  I dont want to present the user two dialogs.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible, the dialog is coming from iOS and not your app.

And there is a good reason for it, security. The dialog is present by the system not you app. This is done so you can hack it so the user always accepts.